# How to add harcode value into a query statement for oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to construct below sql code into oracle

```
  select 'select top 1 ''' + TABLE_NAME + '.' + column_name + ''' from ' + TABLE_NAME + ' where ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' between ''1/27/2010 15:21'' and ''1/27/2010 15:22'' union '
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
  where data_type = 'datetime'
  order by TABLE_NAME


select 'select''' + TABLE_NAME + '.' + column_name + ''' from ' + TABLE_NAME + ' where ROWNUM <= 1 and ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' between ''1/27/2010 15:21'' and ''1/27/2010 15:22'' union '
from all_tab_columns 
WHERE  DATA_TYPE='DATE'
```

Comment: i want my result to be a query text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` is not a string concatenation operator; use `||` instead.

```sql
select 'select ''' || TABLE_NAME || '.' || column_name || ''' from "' || OWNER || '"."' || TABLE_NAME || '" where ROWNUM <= 1 and ' || COLUMN_NAME || ' between DATE ''2010-01-27'' + INTERVAL ''15:21'' HOUR TO MINUTE and DATE ''2010-01-27'' + INTERVAL ''15:22'' HOUR TO MINUTE union '
from all_tab_columns 
WHERE  DATA_TYPE='DATE'
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4fdc0db965ea8f5093b1fea5591691e7)*

You also should not rely on implicit conversion of strings to dates (as your query will fail if the session parameters do not match your expected format or if the user decides to change that format). Instead, you should either use `TO_DATE` with an explicit format model (i.e. `TO_DATE( '1/27/2010 15:21', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI' )` or use literals (i.e. `DATE '2010-01-27' + INTERVAL '15:21' HOUR TO MINUTE` or `TIMESTAMP '2010-01-27 15:21:00'`).

Additionally, you probably want to filter on the schema `OWNER` and include the schema in the `FROM` clause of your output and should use double quotes around the identifiers as they can be case-sensitive.